# HTML5 drag & drop text: preventdefault vs move

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, contenteditable

I have two contenteditable divs with formatted content (e.g. paragraphs in it with bold/italic text etc.) and I would like to move the selected text from one into the another. It works well natively, BUT I want to "clean" the moved text when it is dropped, e.g. remove any formatting ("<b>hello</b>" would become "hello").
So I decided to use HTML5 drop event like this:

```
  dropHandler = function(e) {
    text = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');

    if (document.caretRangeFromPoint)
    {
      range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }
    else if (document.createRange && oe.rangeParent)
    {
      range = document.createRange();
      range.setStart(oe.rangeParent, oe.rangeOffset);
    }

    range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(text));

    return false;
  };
```

It works and puts the "cleaned" (plain) text to the correct position, BUT the initially selected text in the source contenteditable div is not deleted - because of the default behaviour is prevented with "return false" - so the desired text move becomes text copy. How can I achieve the default text move behaviour while also pre-processing the dropped text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Selection) API (except in IE <= 8, which doesn't support it):

```
dropHandler = function(e) {
  text = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');

  if (document.caretRangeFromPoint)
  {
    range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }
  else if (document.createRange && oe.rangeParent)
  {
    range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(oe.rangeParent, oe.rangeOffset);
  }

  // Keep a reference to the text node so we can select it later
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
  range.insertNode(textNode);

  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.deleteFromDocument();
  range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);

  return false;
};
```